# iBuffer: Symbol's value as variable is void: ibuffer-never-show-regexps`

Tags: ibuffer

[emacsWiki/IbufferMode](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/IbufferMode)

> Hide certain buffers
>
> Here’s how to hide all buffers starting with an asterisk.
>
> ```
> (add-to-list 'ibuffer-never-show-regexps "^\\*")
> ```

But when I added into my init file I am getting following error:

`Symbol's value as variable is void: ibuffer-never-show-regexps`. What may be the reason for it?

Comment: I think you want the more recent advice at that link and use `ibuffer-never-show-predicates` instead.

Comment: Ah my bad, it works now. I was having trouble to find `ibuf-ext` package

Comment: `M-x find-library RET ibuf-ext RET`

Comment: p.s. That first suggestion seemed to be at least 18 years out of date.  As such, I've removed it from the Wiki.

Comment: Wow 18 years! Great products always remain alive

Comment: https://www.jwz.org/doc/emacs-timeline.html